How to connect VS Code debugger to a docker compose container with no exposed ports?
I have a docker compose setup that has a few different containers running, but the main container that I am actually working with is a node.js project that does not actually have any exposed ports, as the project itself doesn't need them. It is a chat bot that simply responds to commands when prompted. Is there any way I can get a VS Code debugger to connect to it when running so that I can debug any issues?
You can see here that all 3 other services have port mappings, but the digittron-bot is blank in the ports column. Building and running the compose file works just fine, but when attempting to attach the VS code debugger, I get: Error: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:9229: Could not find any debuggable target. Am I correct in assuming that localhost path is a VS code default? How can I tell it to connect to my "bot" container?
docker ps output:
IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
digittron-bot                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes                                      bot
timothyjmiller/prisma-studio:latest   "/bin/sh prisma-intr…"   27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes             0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp   prisma-studio
postgres:16.2                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres
redis:7.2.4                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago      Up 17 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis

My docker-compose file:
name: digittron
services:
  prisma-studio:
          container_name: prisma-studio
          image: timothyjmiller/prisma-studio:latest
          restart: unless-stopped
          depends_on:
              postgres:
                  condition: service_healthy
          profiles:
              - dev
          environment:
              # prisma studio requires the env variable name be POSTGRES_URL
              POSTGRES_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
          ports:
              - ${PRISMA_STUDIO_PORT}:${PRISMA_STUDIO_PORT}
  postgres:
        image: postgres:16.2
        container_name: postgres
        hostname: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${PSQL_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PSQL_PASS}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${PSQL_DB_NAME}
        ports:
            - ${PSQL_PORT}:${PSQL_PORT}
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        volumes:
            - 'pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        healthcheck:
            test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'pg_isready -q -d $$POSTGRES_DB -U $$POSTGRES_USER']
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
  redis:
        image: redis:7.2.4
        container_name: redis
        restart: always
        ports:
            - ${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}
        command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
        volumes:
            - 'cache:/data'
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
  bot:
        container_name: bot
        build: 
            context: .
            args:
                DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
            secrets:
                - npmrc
                - npmrc_prod
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
            redis:
                condition: service_healthy
        tty: true
        environment:
            DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
        env_file:
            - ./src/.env
volumes:
  pg-data:
    driver: local
  cache:
    driver: local

secrets:
    npmrc:
        file: .npmrc
    npmrc_prod:
        file: .npmrc

